# How do I find dragons to ride?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I killed most dragons in their lairs. I regret that. They're dead when I revisit them and won't respawn.

Basically I want to ride dragons so I can go to hard to reach places. Often I saw a place but it's too hard to climb. There could be a way there that I don't know.

So how do I find infinite number of dragons? I already have a lot of dragon souls and don't need to kill anymore.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Where is a good place to find dragons to kill?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/92008/143571)

Comment: @Wrigglenite well, OP does not want dragons to farm scales or XP. He wants to ride one. There is one that you can always summon and ride, see my answer. Also OP wants to do so to achieve one specific goal, which is unfortunately impossible; I provide alternative means to reach that goal.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the vanilla version of the game, you only get to ride one dragon, [Odahviing](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Odahviing_(Skyrim)). That is just for a quest in the main storyline and you don't get to control him during flight.

If you have the *Dragonborn* expansion, you are able to learn a new shout: [Bend Will](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Bend_Will). If you shout all three words at a non-named dragon (or Odahviing, it seems), then the dragon will land and you will be able to mount and ride them.

If you have the expansion and the shout, you can always summon Odahviing to mount him. If for some reason you don't like good old Od, you can just walk around in the open until a dragon spawns naturally to fight you. Fast traveling to open spaces also seems to cause dragons to spawn sometimes.

Do notice, though, that you will not have full control over their flight. [As per the wiki:](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Dragon_Riding)

> Once airborne, it is not actually possible to fully control the direction of flight. Rather, the dragon will follow certain instructions or orders given to it. If no orders are given, the dragon will simply circle the area.

So it seems that riding a dragon with the purpose of reaching specific high-places might not be possible.

---

Consider a couple alternatives to reach high places:

1. [Horses in Skyrim can climb some absurdly steep slopes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0Ib8D2XhFs). In my opinion they are not true horses, but rather some species derived from mountain goats. They just look like horses due to convergent evolution.
2. In Oblivion skooma would give you a speed boost. This was not the case for Skyrim but some mods actually reinstate that effect, and make it stackable to boost. You could drink an arbitrarily high amount of skooma and you would just get cumulatively faster and faster. [After a few hundred bottles you could go from one end of the world map to the other in seconds (or likely crash the game trying), as if you were wearing the seven league boots of european folklore. Given the physics of the game, this also allowed players to reach high places creatively by climbing on a nearby ledge, drinking a lot of skooma and taking a step forward.](https://youtu.be/08I4UCKsA8E?t=15) Make sure you read the comments there. I don't know if this exploit has been fixed at some point though.
3. If you are on the PC, you may be able to reach many locations by [reciting the correct incantations in the game console](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Console_Commands_(Skyrim)/Locations). If you are truly mad you may also start [from here](https://www.skyrimsearch.com/categories/cells), then work out the hexadecimal codes for other places.

Comment: what about whirlwind?

Comment: @user4951 that works too, but the range is too short for my liking.

Comment: I haven't played Skyrim, but in Fallout 3/NV/4, it's possible for visited 'cells' (in-game areas) to 'reset' if you don't visit them for a while - thereby respawning any enemies and loot. Does this also apply to the dragon lairs that OP mentions? if so, another potential solution would be to 'wait' a certain amount of in-game days (usually 7) to reset the lairs and respawn the dragons.

Comment: While we're talking about stupid horse tricks in Skyrim, you can't go without mentioning the horse-tilt glitch that speedrunners use to launch themselves across the map.

Comment: @Robotnik the same applies to Skyrim. Even in "Cleared" areas, it'll reset after period of time not visiting the cell, something like 30 in-game days at the longest.

Comment: In the expansion don't you actually summon a dragon from another realm outside of Nirn? Not Odahviing who is lured from somewhere in Skyrim to Whiterun.

Comment: @TylerH I don't know, I have never played the expansion.

Comment: @TylerH Yes, that's Durnehviir, though he's from a different DLC. He can't be ridden, though. https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Summon_Durnehviir

Comment: @nick012000 Huh, thanks for refreshing my memory. Been too long since I played, it seems!

Comment: Or simply wisper the "TCL" magic word and walk up anywhere as you clip through everything... or walk into the depth of nirvana.