# Is it possible to use dragon to go to a place we want in the map?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I can ride dragons. However, the dragon doesn't do anything. It just circle winterhold. I want to tell the dragon to go to some places on the map.

None of my keys work. ASDW. None works.

Some websites say I can pick a location on the map and the dragon will move there. How exactly I tell dragons to move to where I want.

[image]

Now, I want to go here

[image]

Is it possible at all? How can I do so?

> Once in the sky, the Dragon will begin a circular flight pattern, not
> unlike the Dragons you might see in the wild. You will not be able to
> directly control how the Dragon flies. It will stay in the area that
> you mounted it, **unless directed to fly somewhere else via the world
> map.** Note that you cannot fast travel on a Dragon to a major hold
> like Solitude or Whiterun, nor can you fly from the island of
> Solstheim to Skyrim or vice versa.

https://www.ign.com/wikis/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim/Dragon_Riding

This one says "unless directed to fly somewhere else via the world map"

How do I use the world map to direct the dragon to fly somewhere else.

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't read the answer to your previous question.

Comment: I did. It says that riding dragon is different than riding a horse. How exactly it's different and how do I go to a place I want. Hang on, I am adding more pics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find dragons to ride?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/375922/how-do-i-find-dragons-to-ride)

Comment: It doesn't really. For example, it says that I can't use dragons to get to high places, however, no reference, and stuff. Also, the question is basically different.

Comment: You're quoting IGN, who's spouting nonsense. "As per the wiki: Once airborne, **it is not actually possible** to fully control the direction of flight." - If you want real dragons you need [Fully Flying Dragons](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/61101?tab=description)

Answer (score 2):

According to this

https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon_Riding

I can fast travel using dragon and that is the only way I can "direct" the dragon somewhere else on the map.

In other word, I cannot use the dragon to travel to hard to reach places. As normally in fast travel I can only travel to places I have visited.

There is no other way to control the dragon.

Someone write this in another question, This answer [How do I find dragons to ride?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/375922/how-do-i-find-dragons-to-ride) also confirms my finding.

My main goal of using a dragon is to fly to hard to reach places and it seems that I can't do that.